# executeQueryAsync doesn't follow success nor fail route

Tags: 2013, javascript, jsom

I have the following code:

```
var markup;

function generateTree() {
    var lines = document.getElementById("imputs").value.split('\n');
    var targetWeb;
    var clientContext;
    var contexto = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var path = lines[i].split(contexto);
        clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(path[1]);            

        var webs = clientContext.get_web().getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
        clientContext.load(webs);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(this.onQuerySucceeded(webs), this.onQueryFailed);            
        markup += '<br>';
    }

    results.innerHTML = markup;
    markup = '';
}

function onQuerySucceeded(webs) {
    for (var j = 0; j < webs.length; j++) {
        markup += webs[j].get_title() + '<br>';
    }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

But debugging I see that the *executeQueryAsync* statement doesn't execute the success or the fail method, it just follows executing `"markup += '<br>';"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you don't pass a function reference as first argument to `executeQueryAsync`. Since you call `this.onQuerySucceeded(webs)` (note the parentheses) you actually pass in the result of that function as first argument.
Since that function does not return anything, that result would be `undefined`.

Comment: +1 correct answer, you need to supply a ``reference`` not a ``call``. So you have to change ``this.onQuerySucceeded(webs)`` to ``onQuerySucceeded``. ``this.onQueryFailed`` **is** a ``reference``. If you do not get the alert it never failed..